# MODBUS protocol coils order

Tags: protocols, modbus, addressing

MODBUS is positioned as a universal data transferring protocol which works in almost every media.

When working with industrial devices they are usually using several slots to maintain different types of I/O modules.
I've read in modbus.org docs that the enumeration of coils (Digital Outputs) is starting from 0 position.

> In the PDU Coils are addressed starting at zero. Therefore coils
> numbered 1-16 are addressed as 0-15

Currently the slots are used in this way. Module 5056D (DO module) is connected as second.

[image]

Would the accessing address to the first Digital Output change from 00 to another if the module is swapped with neighbor modules or it would change only if to insert another DO module in the first slot?

Then I guess it would be 16+1=17; 17-1=16 accessing address=16?

Comment: I think that could only really be answered by the hardware vendor (maybe in the manual).  It may be configurable on the controller.  That said, my guess would be by default the digital output would be accessed in the order that they are installed in the hardware.  In this case the DO module is the only "coils" module so I would expect it to be available as coils 0 -15.  If second DO module was inserted after it I would expect it to be coils 16-31...

Comment: 8-bit or 16-bit block some addresses may consist. These addresses are consecutive (incremental) doesn't mean he's going to be. Although even if address mixed groups of addresses for a particular address heading. The outputs cannot be read on devices. input is provided to read instructions, but is written to the output address.

Comment: Cannot write to output unit(directly). Use internal data bits for this(Reason: System Security (process), the response rate).